# home folders automatic translation Dolphin

Tags: home-directory, language-support, dolphin

I bought a new laptop with ubuntu studio 23.10 installed (in Belgium). There seems to be a problem with an automatic translation of (important) file and folder names. I can't understand if this is related to Dolphin or Ubuntu and I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my attempt to explain the situation:
To ensure compatibility with my other computers I want the main language and folders to be in English (in the system settings the main language of my laptop is set to British English, but my keyboard is set to Dutch). But if I click on one of the main folders of the home folder in Dolphin, it says 'home/Documenten does not exist' Dolphin links or looks for the Dutch translation of the home folders Desktop, Downloads, Templates, etc.
In the command console I see that the home folders are in English.
Moreover, if I create or copy a file to the Desktop (in Dolphin), it does not appear on my visual desktop. At a certain moment shortcuts (symbolic links) to all folders of 'home' popped up on my visual desktop, and I removed them (via the visual desktop). But the actual folders were deleted! these weren't shortcuts...

output of command 'ls -R' :
.:
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Videos
./Desktop:
test-hier-op-desktop.txt
./Documents:
./Downloads:
./Music:
./Videos:

Comment: check `.config/users-dirs.dirs` for any alterations. Oh and those folders get recreated on each  new login. (technically you can remove all non-hidden directories in /home/$USER/ and on the next login those will return (in the location users-dirs,dirs is set to)

Comment: I solved these issues. Several things got mixed up but this was the solution:
1) In the command console check if the main home folders Desktop, Downloads, Documents, Music, etc. still exist (if necessary, create them with the mkdir command).
2) Read this explanation about xdg-user-dirs-update :
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdg-user-dirs-update.1.html
 
and adapt the (hidden) file  ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs  

3) in Dolphin, right click on the home folder and choose 'edit' (to remove the links to translated file names)